# Which technology to go from here

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app

With windows 10 just around the corner I am bit confused on WPF and universal application. My goal is to build a line of business application, but i am not sure which technology to choose for WPF or a universal app? Does a universal application now include WPF, is WPF being supported or just been tossed away?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is an on-topic post. That said: I haven't seen an official statement from Microsoft, but the general pattern is that when a new GUI API appears, they stop work on the previous one, but do not deprecate it. So, take your pick. Just be aware that the WinRT/Universal approach means a XAML-based API that has many fewer features than WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to go for a c#/xaml technology.

Implement a good MVVM pattern, isolate your core domain, and adapt your UI code (XAML) for each specific device you want to target (Windows Phone, Desktop, WinRT...Whatever).

You cannot be sure of the technology, but you can be sure that MVVM/C#/XAML will stay for long.